# "error": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error')"

Tags: undefined, prisma

I'm using prisma with MongoDB, nextjs.
I'M TRYING TO MAKE A POST REQUEST USING POSTMAN
*THIS IS MY API*

```
if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
        const data = req.body;
        const taskResponse = await createTask(data);
        if (taskResponse.error) {
          throw new Error(taskResponse.error);
        }
        return res.status(201).json({ createdTask: taskResponse.createdTask });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
      }
  }
```

BUT I'M GETTING THIS ERROR:

> **"error": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error')"**

Below is my create task function:

```
export const createTask = async (task) => { 
  try {
    const createdTask = await prisma.tasks.create({ data: task }); 
    return {task: createdTask};
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating task:', error);
  }
};
```

I want to update my database using post request.

Answer (score 0):

In your `createTask` function you are return an **object** with the key task, but in your API route you are **expecting** an **object** with keys `createdTask` and this could be causing the error

try

```
export const createTask = async (task) => { 
  try {
    const createdTask = await prisma.tasks.create({ data: task }); 
    return { createdTask }; // Update key to match the expected response in the API route i think this is your problem
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating task:', error);
    return { error: error.message }; // Return an object with 'error' key or return the error and use it directly
  }
};
```

```
if (req.method === 'POST') {
  try {
    const data = req.body;
    const taskResponse = await createTask(data);
    if (taskResponse.error) {
      throw new Error(taskResponse.error);
    }
    return res.status(201).json({ createdTask: taskResponse.createdTask }); // Update key to match the response from createTask i talk about it above
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
}
```